# JavaScript Intl.DateTimeFormat.format vs Date.toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I would like to print a string representing a Date, using a specific timezone, locale, and display options.

Which one of these should I use?

1. [Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format)
2. [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

It seems like they return identical results.

```js
const event = new Date(1521065710000);

const options = {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  weekday: 'short',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
};

console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
// "Wed, March 14, 3:15 PM PDT"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(event));
// "Wed, March 14, 3:15 PM PDT"
```

Comment: For all practical purposes, they are identical. *toLocaleString* was originally purely implementation dependent, but now it also supports the same options as the Intl object, both are based on the [*ECMA-402 Internationalization API*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/#intl-object). Note that ECMA-402 does not specify the format, it only requires conformity with regional or cultural preferences, which might differ between implementations, even for the same language and region. So you may not get exactly consistent results (but pretty close).

Comment: @RobG Yes of course, awakening typo... and what I thought to remember about perfs was probably just [the note in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Performance).

Comment: @Kaiido—no problem. ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is very close to being off–topic as opinion based, but here goes anyway.

> Which one of these should I use?

*Date.prototype.toLocaleString* was originally solely implementation dependent and varied quite a bit across browsers. When support for the Intl object was added (ECMAScript 2015, ed 6) then *toLocaleString* was allowed to support the same options. While support isn't mandated by ECMA-262, probably all current implementations support it.

Note that this did not remove the allowed implementation variability, it just provided some formatting options based on language, region and dialect (and also timezone options based on the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) identifiers and values).

The Intl object (and hence *toLocaleString*) is based on [ECMA-402](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/#intl-object), which doesn't strictly specify formatting, so there is still some room for implementations to differ. The biggest differences are in regard to timezone names (for which there is no standard) and placement of commas, spaces, etc.

However, for most practical purposes, whether you use the Intl object or *toLocaleString* is up to you, I don't think there's any technical reason to prefer one over the other. While the results for both should be identical for a particular implementation, don't expect the resulting string to be **exactly** identical across implementations or to conform to a particular format for a given [BCP 47 language tag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646).

Comment: Thanks, this is the information I was interested in. I'm happy to edit my question to not be off-topic. Maybe `Are there any advantages / disadvantages to using these two approaches?` or `Why do there exist two ways to accomplish the following?` or `What is the history of these two methods?` or some other suggestion

Answer (score 7):

Addition to points that others issued, I saw a difference with ***default options***:

```js
const date = new Date(1521065710000)

console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'))  // "3/14/2018, 10:15:10 PM"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date))  // "3/14/2018"
```

<sup>Tested on Chrome v72, v85, v121 / Firefox v122 / Bun.js v1.0.25, v1.0.27 / Node.js v14, v20.8.0, v21.5.0.</sup>

---

The output of *`new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format()` (with default options)* is similar to **`.toLocaleDateString` (not <s>`.toLocaleString`</s>) (with default options)**:

```js
const date = new Date(1708341724000)

const formatted1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date)
const formatted2 = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US')

console.log(formatted1) // "2/19/2024"
console.log(formatted1 === formatted1) // true
```

**But I'm not sure is it correct in all locales and runtimes, or not!**

---

If you want an output like **`.toLocaleString()` (with default `options`)**, you can pass these options to `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```js
{
  // https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-datetimeformat-abstracts
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
}
```

Example:

```js
const date = new Date(1708341724000)

const formatted1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  // https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-datetimeformat-abstracts
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
}).format(date)
const formatted2 = date.toLocaleString('en-US')

console.log(formatted1) // "2/19/2024, 11:22:04 AM"
console.log(formatted1 === formatted1) // true
```

**But I'm not sure is it correct in all locales and runtimes, or not!**

---

If you want an output like **`.toLocaleTimeString()`** (with default `options`), you can pass `{timeStyle: 'medium'}` to `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:
Example:

```js
const date = new Date(1708341724000)

const formatted1 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',
  {timeStyle: 'medium'}, // https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-date-time-style-format
).format(date)
const formatted2 = date.toLocaleString('en-US')

console.log(formatted1) // "11:22:04 AM"
console.log(formatted1 === formatted1) // true
```

**But I'm not sure is it correct in all locales and runtimes, or not!**

Comment: Yes, the Date AI's have a simple, straightforward way of specifying which components should be included, ie. toLocaleDateString() vs toLocaleTimeString() vs toLocalString().   With the Intl API's it seems to be inferred from the options.

Answer (score 7):

If you re-use the same format a lot of times, re-using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` object seems to be better from a performance perspective.

```js
const format =  {
    weekday: 'long',
    month: 'long',
    day: '2-digit',
};
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', format);
const start1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) dateTimeFormat.format(new Date());
console.log('re-use Intl.DateTimeFormat', performance.now() - start1);

const start2 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) new Date().toLocaleString('en', format);
console.log('use toLocaleString', performance.now() - start2);
```

When I run this snippet in Chrome 105, it gives me a result like this:

```
re-use Intl.DateTimeFormat 17.299999952316284
use toLocaleString 876.0999999046326
```

Answer (score 3):

The Internationalisation API [isn't supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization) in all browsers just yet - notably, IE10 and below and UC Browser for Android 11.8. If you want to support those browsers, use ToLocaleString. (Though if the Internationalisation API isn't supported, what ToLocalString returns is implementation-dependent.)

Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format is designed for the use of formatting large groups of Dates - rather than setting the locale and options every time, you set them once and use the resulting format function from then on.

Comment: At this point `Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format` [is supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat_format) across major browsers

Comment: @IliasT As much as I'd love to drop support for IE10, I still have paying customers STILL USING IE8, despite all the "Please for the love of God no" banners I slam them with. "All major browsers" isn't the same thing as "the browsers my customers use".

Comment: Haha fair. Yes, "major browsers" is not the same as "all browsers".